# How AND expressions are evaluated?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, exists, logical-operators, iif

I have the following situation:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] BIGINT
)

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID])
VALUES (1)
      ,(2)
      ,(3)

DECLARE @IDForSearch VARCHAR(4) = 'TEXT'
```

If we try to extract record using our wrong type parameter:

```
SELECT IIF( EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM @DataSource WHERE [ID] = @IDForSearch), 'Found', 'Missing')
```

we are getting the error below:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 14
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.
```

But If I add a simple isNumeric check everything is working fine:

```
SELECT IIF( ISNUMERIC(@IDForSearch) = 1 AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM @DataSource WHERE [ID] = @IDForSearch), 'Found', 'Missing')
```

I firstly thought that the first part of the expression is executed:

```
ISNUMERIC(@IDForSearch) = 1
```

and because it fails, the second one is not executed and the error is not thrown.

But, if I change the expressions places everything is working again:

```
SELECT IIF( EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM @DataSource WHERE [ID] = @IDForSearch) AND ISNUMERIC(@IDForSearch) = 1, 'Found', 'Missing')
```

Why there is no error in these situations?

Comment: I don't think it's based on the order you write it in (as you've shown). The database engine (you haven't specified which one you are using, btw) can pick the order it prefers and it probably decides that ``IsNumeric()`` has a lower cost than a ``select``. What I mean is that the query optimizer will make a cost-based decision on which order to use.

Comment: and to add to what acfrancis is saying, just about anything *could* cause the engine to change its decision at some future point in time - any patches to the server, changes to indexes, etc. It's unfortunate but there's no way to *force* it to evaluate the `WHERE` clause in one particular order.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's exactly what I am worried about. I am going to split the expressions in order to avoid future issues.

Comment: To be fair, I think the implicit conversion only failed because the variable was set to 'TEXT'. There are lots of ways to protect against that.

Comment: I think that is not correct. See my answer bellow. I don't use "TEXT"

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is some internal cast (I speak about SQL 212), because:

```
select IIF( 1='a','Found','Missing')
```

results in

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int.
```

and

```
select IIF(isnumeric('a')=1 and 1='a','Found','Missing')
```

returns

```
Missing
```